# Rails The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm adding a second index file for a table called wostatuses.
The first index (index.html.erb) works fine.
But, the 2nd index (index2.html.erb) gets "The error occurred while evaluating nil.each" on the line:

```
<% @wostatuses.each do |wostatus| %>
```

The controller has:

```
class WostatusesController < ApplicationController
# GET /wostatuses
# GET /wostatuses.json
def index
  @wostatuses = Wostatus.order("position")

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @wostatuses }
  end
 end
```

index.html.erb and index2.html.erb  have:

```
  <% @wostatuses.each do |wostatus| %>
```

In routes, I have:

```
  get "wostatuses/index"
  get "wostatuses/index2"
```

Thanks for the help!!

UPDATE -

```
<% Wostatus.find_each do |wostatus| %> worked!!!!
```

But, I need the records ordered by wostatus.position.  How do I do that?

Comment: @wostatuses is nil; how are you routing index2 and filling the instance variable?

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to Rails.  "How are you routing to index2?"  I have the routes showing above. the URL is http://localhost:3000/wostatuses/index2 - "How are you filling the instance variable?"  I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: I tried   <% Wostatus.find.each do |wostatus| %> and got Couldn't find Wostatus without an ID

Comment: <% Wostatus.find_each do |wostatus| %> worked!!!!

Comment: But, I need the records ordered by wostatus.position.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make an action for **index2** in your controller with the same code of **index1**. You can also make a method with the common functionality and use the method in both actions in order to write re-utilizable code.